# Is it safe to use a tower case pc horizontally? Does it affect HDDs, power supply?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply

I've got a PC with damaged GPU card, the card itself doesn't seem to work when the PC case is in the default position (it doesn't even start and when it does it resets itself quite often). Everything works perfectly fine when I place the case on its side (left or right, doesn't matter). The only downside is I can't use the CD-ROM, but I don't do this too often anyway. I'm using the PC lying flat on it's right side (so the CPU is "on the ground").

Is it safe to use the PC this way? Won't it damage, let's say, the power supply, or the hard disk that work in horizontal positions? As far as I know in "desktop cases" the power supply is in the same position as in tower cases? My case is Cooler Master Elite 330, the power supply is OCZ ModXStream Pro 500W and I've got two Samsung F3 500 GB HDDs.

Sorry if it's a stupid question, just wondering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely fine.  Just don't plop it over as it's running, that's the only thing that would damage hard drives.  PSUs are solid state (outside of the cooling fan), so not a concern either.

I would, however, be slightly concerned about the gfx card, as it sounds like it may eventually cause a short.